# Overriding error404.html.twig entailing a 500 error (Twig & Symfony3)

Tags: php, templates, twig, symfony

I encountered this problem : when I want to replace the default error pages of the twig bundle (following for that the requested methods everyone can see [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html)), I'm in peace as long as I'm not creating a generic `error.html.twig`, or a `error404.html.twig`. But, oddly, my `error403.html.twig` works as a wonder.

I compared my error templates with each other, using the OS X Kaleidoscope, and the few differences are completely benign.

I give you my error.html.twig, as an instance :

```
{% extends (is_mobile() and not is_tablet())? 
':Mobile:layout.html.twig' 
:
':Full:layout.html.twig'
%}

{% block title %}
   Une erreur est survenue : {{ status_text }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
   <div id="h1-error">Aie !<br>Le serveur ne répond pas</div>
{% set table=[
["*","*","*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
["*","*","*","*","5","0","0","*","*"],
["*","*","*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
["*","*","A","U","C","U","N","E","*"],
["*","*","*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
["*","*","*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
["*","*","*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
["*","R","É","P","O","N","S","E","*"],
["*","*","*","*","*","*","*","*","*"]
]
%}
<div id="table">
<table border-collapse="separate">
  {% for i in 0..8 %}
  <tr>
    {% for j in 0..8 %}
      {% if table[i][j]!='*' %}
        <td class="special">
          <span id="symbol">
            {{table[i][j]}}
          </span>
        </td>
      {% else %}
        <td>
          <span id="symbol">
            {{random('QWERTZUIOPLKJHGFDSAYXCVBNM')}}
          </span>
        </td>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
</div>

<div id="backHome">
<br>
    <a class="mr-btn mr-btn-primary" id="back-button" href="{{path('mr_platform_home')}}">
  Retour à l'accueil
    </a>
<br>
</div>

{{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Furthermore, the path of those files is the right one : `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/[file]`

And, as a final point, my prod log is the following, when I try a test url like http://localhost:8888/AugustProject/web/test (I'm working on a local server, but the same problem occurs on a distant one) :

```
request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /test"" at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MamyRoom/var/cache/prod/classes.php line 2774 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /test\" at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MamyRoom/var/cache/prod/classes.php:2774, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MamyRoom/var/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1000)"} []
```

...letting one think that the code was not the source of the bug (?)

What step did I miss ?

Thanks a lot, in advance !

Comment: Have you cleared your cache in prod ? `app/console c:c --env=prod`

Comment: Hi DOZ, thanks ! When I clear my cache I do it with a BSD alias 'AugustClear' that do remove the entire content of the var/cache directory. But I did the command you mentioned, and the bug persists.

Comment: When you call http://localhost:8888/AugustProject/web/test do you have a blank page ?

Comment: I get the 500 error page of Chrome, with a sad page emoticon, so it not a completely blank page

Comment: Anyone else who would see the point ?